# How do I show this fact about product of expectation value?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

I have the following problem:

> We have $X,Y$ two random variables taking values in $\Bbb{N}$. We assume that they take only two values. I want to show that $X,Y$ are independent iff. $\Bbb{E}(XY)=\Bbb{E}(X)\Bbb{E}(Y)$.

I somehow get confused with the "...only two values." Because as I understood it in general if we only consider $\Bbb{E}(X)=\sum_{n\in \Bbb{N}} n P(X=n)$. But now how do I need to interprete the fact that they only take two values. Do I only have $\Bbb{E}(X)=n_1P(X=n_1)+n_2P(X=n_2)$ and similarly for $\Bbb{E}(Y)=m_1P(Y=m_1)+m_2P(Y=m_2)$?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes.  When an integer valued random variable takes only two values, it means only those two values have a non-zero probability mass .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By replacing $X$ by $aX+b$ for suitable $a$ and $b$, you can arrange that the two values taken by $X$ are $0$ and $1$. Likewise for $Y$. Then
$$
P(X=1,Y=1))=E(XY)=E(X)\cdot E(Y)=P(X=1)\cdot P(Y=1),
$$
and
$$
\eqalign{
P(X=0,Y=1)
&=E((1-X)Y)=E(Y)-E(XY)=E(Y)-E(X)E(Y)\cr
&=(1-E(X))E(Y)=P(X=0)P(Y=1),\cr
}
$$
etc. It follows that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your interpretation of the problem statement is correct.

Comment: ah okey perfect so I will try it in this way.

Comment: Not simpler. The proof won’t work for case of more values: in general zero correlation is not sufficient for independence

Comment: @Ilya Thanks for your input but is there a counterexample which shows really nice that this statement do not hold if we only assume that $X,Y\in L_2(P)$ and not that thy only takes two variables?

Comment: @wave see for example this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179511/why-zero-correlation-does-not-necessarily-imply-independence

Comment: Oops -- you're of course right, @Ilya. I glossed over the bidrectional implication. Thanks for the correction!